# How to tell apt-get to install another version of Eclipse?

Tags: apt

`apt-get` installs Eclipse version 3.5 when I do this:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform
```

However I would like to install version 3.6.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse 3.5 is the latest version in repositories.apt-get installs the latest version automatically, so there is nothing to do with apt-get.

Instead you can download eclipse 3.6 (Helios) from [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell apt to install a specific version as follows:

```
apt-get install package=version
```

example:

```
apt-get install eclipse-platform=3.5.2-6ubuntu1.1
```

But AFAIK the version 3.6 is not available in the repo. It is better to install manually . Check a similar thread here [How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse/26633#26633)