# Where is the default folder for Apps?

Tags: filesystem

I am relatively new to the linux world. I use OSX at home and Windows at work. In those worlds, there is a default folder for applications (`C:\Program Files`, `/Applications`). Is there any such directory in Ubuntu?

I understand that this is not very important and any location in the file system should be ok, but was just wondering whether there are such *standard* locations (I think there would be one). For instance where is Firefox or Libre Office (that are installed by default)?

Got this question when I was trying to install eclipse. Downloaded the zip, and was wondering...

Comment: You may also be interested in [How to install Eclipse?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Ubuntu (Linux) follows the [filesystem hierachy structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). There is a description of the main directories in that link.

The location where software gets installed depends on how you install it. If you use the most obvious method (Ubuntu Software Center/`.deb`'s) it generally gets installed to the default locations. In that case libraries will end up in `/usr/lib/` (Libraries for the binaries in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/sbin/`.) and the executable in `/bin` (Essential command binaries that need to be available in single user mode; for all users, e.g., `cat`, `ls`, `cp`), `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin` (Non-essential command binaries (not needed in single user mode); for all users).

Some other important directories are `/opt` and `/usr/local/share`.

`/opt`: Optional application software packages. Jasperserver (a stand-alone and embeddable reporting server) for instance installs into `/opt`.

`/usr/local` is for data that must be stored on the local host and is used for installing software/data that are not part of the standard operating system distribution. In this directory you will find `lib` for libraries en `bin` for executables.

You can use `system settings`, `main menu` to browse for executables. Or from command line with `locate`. Or inside `Ubuntu Software Center` you can browse all the files that are used for a package. Examples using `locate` and `libreoffice`:

```
locate libreoffice|grep bin
```

will show `/usr/bin/libreoffice`.

Sidenote: Eclipse is in the software center so no need to download a zip (unless you want the newest version and not the most stable one):

[image]

Comment: Rather than running locate, you could run `which libreoffice`

Comment: `which` assumes you know the executable's name. `locate` does not so with an extra pipe and a grep it should be easier to use.