# Where can I find the Transmission executable

Tags: appmenu

I'm trying to download a torrent, and Transmission bittorrent isn't showing up on the list of programs to run the file with, and I don't know where to locate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the default folder for Apps?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60826/where-is-the-default-folder-for-apps) This can also help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122930/how-to-make-firefox-open-magnet-links-in-transmission

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate, but I think my answer might fit on the other question.  If it gets closed, please merge my answer into the other question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Usually, the binaries of the programs that you download are located in `/usr/bin`, along with some other directories that could hold these binaries. You can tackle this through several ways.

#### Short Answer:

Transmission is located in `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk`.

#### Long Answer:

I'm no expert in this, but here's how I would go about locating where transmission is:

1. First, you need to know what exactly is the name of the application, the name of the binary, because it might not be a straight-forward `transmission`. So, you could simply do `ls -l /usr/bin | grep transmission`. This will output all the files that have `transmission` in them. When I execute that command, I get this:

   ```
   alaa@aa-lu:~$ ls /usr/bin | grep transmission
   transmission-cli
   transmission-create
   transmission-edit
   transmission-gtk
   transmission-remote
   transmission-show
   ```

   `gtk` usually denotes that this is a "graphical" program, so there you have it, Transmission is located in `/usr/bin` and it called `transmission-gtk`. So, browse to that file when you're opening your torrent file, and it should work.
2. If you don't get any output from the above `ls` command, then `transmission` might not be installed in the first place. You can check if it's installed by using `dpkg`:

   ```
   alaa@aa-lu:~$ dpkg -l | grep transmission
   ii  transmission-cli                          2.77-0ubuntu1                          i386         lightweight BitTorrent client (command line programs)
   ii  transmission-common                       2.77-0ubuntu1                          all          lightweight BitTorrent client (common files)
   ii  transmission-gtk                          2.77-0ubuntu1                          i386         lightweight BitTorrent client (GTK interface)
   ```

   This tells me that `transmission-gtk` is infact installed.
3. If you didn't find it in `/usr/bin`, you can use the command `whereis transmission-gtk`

   ```
   alaa@aa-lu:~$ whereis transmission-gtk
   transmission-gtk: /usr/bin/transmission-gtk /usr/bin/X11/transmission-gtk /usr/share/man/man1/transmission-gtk.1.gz
   ```

   Ignore the other two locations.

Comment: You can also just run `whereis <application name> `

Comment: @Esso, yup, was about to add it. I also want to add `dkpg -L`, or that he can look in `/usr/share/applications`, but I think it would be going too far =), and turns out it's a duplicate.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think that the `whereis` addition is particularly useful. The thing is, in this particular case, you actually need to know that it's transmission-gtk, and not transmision, transmission-bt, transmission-qt, or transmission-something-else. Actually running `whereis <application name>` for transmission, returns something irrelevant to the executable.

Comment: Yes, that's why in step 1, I mentioned that "_you need to know what exactly is the name of the application_" =). The steps were meant to be followed in order. (1) Find the name of the application, then (2) search in `/usr/bin`, and if not present, (3) search for the binary using `whereis`, and if not present, (4) do a `dpkg -L transmission-gtk` or look for what's being executed in the `/usr/share/application` entry.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk` for Ubuntu.

PS: In case you have a different version, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

`which my-random-command` in this case substitute `transmission-gtk` for `my-random-command`.  Listing and grepping is bad for people that might have user based installs of things that are in their PATH, but not in the /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin you would expect...say for example ~/bin.