# Where can I find a folder containing icons of all my applications, that I can double-click?

Tags: filesystem, files, icons

Where can I find the folder where I can see icons of my applications and click on them as I am accustomed to from other operating systems?  (N.B. Please see my comments re duplications.)

Comment: Duplicate?  Yes, and no. This is an answer that I have been looking for and stumbled across quite by accident. I wanted to know where this folder was, and found it, and I am sure other former Mac OS X users want this, too. The other answers are long and complicated, when all I wanted was this one. I created this Q&A to help others in my boat.

Comment: Umm... you click the icon in the top left of the screen and look under "applications"?

Comment: @ muru,  it gives me the path to the folder I seek, but it doesn't ASK my question. "App view slidie out thing" isn't very helpful when trying to look up an answer. If I were conducting a search, I would never arrive at that post. I think it's important to have a meaningful question as well as meaningful answer. So I posted this Q&A. People in my situation will find the question they expect and the answer they understand.

Comment: @pussi, that does not answer my question. I want to know where the folder is that I can open and see the icons. Then I can manipulate them in ways that I am accustomed to in other operating systems. It is a very specific question.

Comment: I think you should read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't exactly one, because the filesystem structure is different, but I suggest you go here:

```
/usr/share/applications
```

There you will find icons of your various installed applications with the friendly names you expect (Adobe Reader 9, Frogatto, Opera, LibreOffice Calc, etc.). And while not exactly equivalent to the Mac's Applications folder, you will find that here you can double-click on applications to launch, just as you would in Mac OS X.

For a detailed explanation of the filesystem structure, and how it's not exactly equivalent to Apple's Mac OS X, go here:

[Where is the default folder for Apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60826/where-is-the-default-folder-for-apps)

Hope this helps.