# Unable to install Eclipse manually

Tags: eclipse, fortran

I have just started Linux. I have a SBC(Atom processor) on which I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now I am trying to install Fortran IDE.

For which I have learnt that I need to install OpenJDK first, then Eclipse Juno and at last the Phortran plugin for Eclipse.

I have no Internet access so I had follow the below steps for manual installation.

1. First download the eclipse tar.gz package (downloaded: eclipse-parallel-juno-linux-gtk.tar).
2. Then right-click the eclipse tar.gz and choose the extract here option to extract the tar.gz package.You can also use the command line to extract the tar.gz package.

   ```
   # tar xzf eclipse-cpp-juno-linux-gtk.tar.gz
   ```
3. Move to /opt/ folder.

   ```
   # mv eclipse /opt/
   ```

   Use `sudo` if the above command gives permission denied message.

   ```
   # sudo mv eclipse /opt/
   ```
4. Create a desktop file and place it into /usr/share/applications

   ```
   # sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   and copy the following to the `eclipse.desktop` file

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Eclipse 
   Type=Application
   Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Comment=Integrated Development Environment
   NoDisplay=false
   Categories=Development;IDE
   Name[en]=eclipse.desktop
   ```
5. Create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` using

   ```
   # cd /usr/local/bin
   # sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse
   ```
6. Now its the time to launch eclipse.

   ```
   # /opt/eclipse/eclipse  -clean  &
   ```

Now at step 5, when I type the command `sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse` , I get an this error message:

```
ln: Failed to create symbolic link './eclipse': File exists.
```

Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the following commands:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/eclipse  
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse

sudo /opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean &
```

If you have errors after these commands check this question (answer 2) [askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Comment: The first command deletes the actual eclipse binary, doesn't it? I think you meant `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/eclipse`. Then use `sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse eclipse`.

Comment: hi kamil & phoibos just tried as you have said, gives me same error msg: "ln: failed to create symbolic link 'eclipse': Fileexists"

Comment: Okay, just tried the command "sudo rm /usr/local/bin/eclipse" and it pop'd error msg: "rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/eclipse': No such file or directory"

Comment: it said "eclipse:"

Comment: it gives me same error "ln: failed to create symbolic link 'eclipse': File exists"

Comment: it lists some 15 files in it, would you like me to mention those?

Comment: yes it is, in green.

Comment: it just took it, and next i tried " /opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean &" and it has given [1] 2030

Comment: it gave me "[1]+ Done       /opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean"

Comment: I just did and it gave me "[1] 1918"

Comment: @veerendar - the way we reply with asking for more information is by editing your question - reading this stuff in comments is very difficult.  Please can you edit your question with relevant information and delete your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: @kamil - similar comment - please edit your answer with relevant information and delete your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: @kamil - I have downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse for Parallel Application Developer and done all the steps as listed and guess what. it worked! cheers!

Comment: @fossfreedom - I am sorry this is my first visit and was not aware, will follow your guidelines for all my next visits. Thanks!