# Install Eclipse

Tags: installation, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

I am new at linux.

I need to install Eclipse on my pc but I have no idea how to do that.

Could somebody please help me ??

here you can find the file I downloaded : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR1/eclipse-cpp-juno-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can install Eclipse from the Ubuntu software center open it up and search for Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the Ubuntu Software Center to install a lot of popular software without needing to manually download files.

Open up your Dash Home by clicking the Ubuntu logo in the top-left or hitting the Windows/Ubuntu key on your keyboard, then begin typing "Ubuntu Software Center".

Once the app appears, you can hit enter at any time to complete the command and it will launch the first matching item in the list.

From within the Ubuntu Software Center, you can search for apps.

Search for Eclipse and it should appear in the list. Simply click to install!

Comment: how do i select which version i want to install?

Comment: The current version of Eclipse in the USC is a release candidate for an Ubuntu build of 3.8.0. I would imagine newer versions are rolled out more slowly via this method. If you need a specific version, or the latest one, you should visit the [official downloads page for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download the .tar.gz package from the eclipse website http://eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux , extract the package... then change the authorization of the file named eclipse by running the command

`$ chmod 777 eclipse`
then everytime you want the IDE to run, just enter into the directory where the IDE is extracted by terminal and type....
`$ ./eclipse`

done... :)

Comment: Where do I run the command ? in the terminal ? I extracted it to the Desktop. so I need to enter to the Desktop in the terminal and do what ? I tried what what you said and I did not achieve any success

Comment: No need to use the `chmod` command for this. Right click on the `eclipse` file, the, go to `Properties` > `Permission` tab and check the checkbox which asks you to allow the execution of the file as a program.