# Eclipse IDE just show "General" and "CVS" in wizard

Tags: eclipse, ide

I just installed Eclipse IDE using Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic, but in both cases it don't shows for example "Java Project" in the wizard (File > New), just shows General and CVS. How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how to install eclipse](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Comment: I had the same problem. I used Tato's solution: sudo eclipse -clean This worked fine. However, this opens eclipse as root. I think that simply running this in terminal: eclipse -clean would most likely do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed just eclipse-platform. For Java development you need to install:

```
apt-get install eclipse-jdt
```

Comment: Hi! It's already installed @willi

Comment: Have tried a fresh workspace?

Comment: Yes, continue with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I run in a terminal sudo eclipse -clean with this I could see the other resources, then close eclipse and run again eclipse normally and let me see the other projects. Maybe this work for others.