# Virtual installation: where to find the ISO

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, virtualbox, c

I'm running windows 7 on my computer (64-bit) and I need to install Ubuntu 12.10 (kernel: 3.5.0-17-generic) virtually.

I've installed VirtualBox from Oracle but I can't find the iso image for this Ubuntu version. Plus, I've read that there are certain procedures in order to install and write C/C++ programs (some people said that installing eclipse was a problem and others said that the GCC compiler was a problem) and that it's not as simple as windows.

So would anyone please tell me where to find the iso image and what steps should I do to successfully start writing parallel programs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

First set up the virtual machine (VM), and download a suitable ISO file from the [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Personally, I would recommend sticking with a LTS release, in this case Ubuntu 12.04. Mount the ISO file as the VM's optical disk and install from there.

Boot the new VM, login, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

That will set up [the basic things you need](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/build-essential) in order to compile and build packages on Ubuntu.

Next, install Eclipse from a [downloaded archive](https://askubuntu.com/a/145018/131942) or (even easier) from [the package](https://askubuntu.com/a/118377/131942).

You asked about Eclipse, but you might also want to give the [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) a try, which also offers a similar cross-platform IDE experience.