# Download executables on Ubuntu

Tags: downloads, executable

I'm (kind of) new on ubuntu and I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to download executables. For example, I tried to download Eclipse and a Java environment this morning. On my Windows XP PC, this would have worked fine, I would have double clicked on the download and the executable would have opened. However, on Ubuntu, when I do that I get a .tar folder and, even by extracting it, I don't see where it gets me.

Could anyone help ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: What tar is it?

Comment: Well extract tar, open terminal, move to extracted directory, and see what you have there, using `ls -la`, look you may find executable file. For example if its **eclipse** just run in terminal `./eclipse`

Comment: It says it's a tar.gz.

I'm not too sure about how terminal works, but I'll try and find a good tutorial on the web. But isn't there any other way than executing the terminal every time I want to open it? Supposing I want to do some programming for example. Isn't there some way of having it in the dock or on the desktop? That would be more practical than executing through the terminal !

Comment: @ThomasCunningham for that you must make an `.desktop` file, and pin it to dock or unity or any launcher.

Comment: the 'apt-get install' advice is generally good - or you can use the Ubuntu Software Center, which is the GUI equivalent.  However, specifically for eclipse, there are some arguments to downloading the .tar.gz file and using it instead - there is some discussion of this and how to do it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE and http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same confusion when moving from Windows. "Where's the installer executable to download and install?" I would ask.

In Ubuntu you've got a few other options, mainly the Software Centre (graphical) or a command-line installer like `apt-get`. I like apt-get. Once you get used to it (and trust it), it is *so* much easier.

On the command-line, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Enter password, confirm the download (because it's ~200Mb), and it will get and install the application for you.

If you don't have an executable in your system, typing the name in the command-line will often give you useful suggestions of what packages to download. So if you're looking for javac, say, entering it will give you a number of package target names that contain the javac program.

When you want specific versions of applications, things get a little more involved. If you can track down the `.deb` file you want, Ubuntu will recognise it as such and bring up the Software Centre installer screen if you double-click on it. If you have a tar file as you mentioned above, generally you extract it and then run an executable contained within it. But with tar files you may run into library compatibility issues.

Comment: All right, that helps a lot! Thanks for the great answer Ash !

Comment: No problem. I always think that when I was starting out with Linux, someone should have sat me down and said, "Forget that way of installing, embrace apt-get, it will solve a problem you didn't know you had". Good luck with your codin'.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar xvzf packagename.tar.gz 

./configure

make 

make install
```

Comment: I think, the complicated stuff should be left for more advanced users. Beginners usually don't want and don't need to compile from source. Also, your answer lacks a lot of important information, for instance that software installed that way often can not be uninstalled, at least not easily (check out checkinstall for that purpose), or that there are usually options that should be passed to configure (always, I repeat, always run ./configure --help first).