# which java should i use for ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, java

I'm new to ubuntu (but i like it a lot), so please bear with me.

I want to install Java, but which one should I install?

- The RPM or the normal one?
- 32bit or 64bit?

From what I know, even windows 64 bit is still using java 32 bit. This thing make me confused.

I'm asking here just to make sure everything is going to be all right, because I will need my system to be ready to code (eclipse :D) pretty soon, so I want to avoid any trouble now.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my basic question.

Comment: I don't think there is a reason **not** to use 64-bit Java on 64-bit OS, be it Linux or Windows.

Comment: @MadMike because im new to ubuntu, i prefer to avoid using terminal for now. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: However, im still confuse, which one should i download? The RPM or the other one?

Comment: Use the DEB-files whenever possible

Comment: Since you're using Ubuntu there's no reason to install RPM since RPM is a package manager specific to Redhat/Fedora distros. Ubuntu uses the Debian package system. Since you're on a 64 bit system you should be installing 64 bit software. The only reason to install 32 bit software is if an application you're installing isn't available for 64 bit and in that case your package manager doing the install will handle the 32 bit installs for you. So as a general rule always install the highest bit that your system is compatible with, in your case 64 bit. The only reason to use RPM on a Ubuntu system

Comment: Follow the advice of the accepted answer in that question. You don't need to use the terminal. Java is installable from the Software Center.

Comment: If you need to install the latest eclipse, usw this [article] ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu, you don't need to worry about this. Open the software center and search for eclipse. The installation of eclipse will also take care of the Java jdk.

Comment: wow, this is a good news, even better than windows :D I will try it out and let you know what happened. Thanks :D

Comment: And one more question, will it automatically choose what version i download? (like indigo, juno etc)

Comment: the version of eclipse will be the latest one in the Ubuntu repository. So, you will not given a chance to select the version. in 13.04 it is Indigo, afaik

Comment: @madmike when someone says he need eclipse to code java, you don't need much intelligence to infer that he needs jdk. fyi, without jdk you can't develop java code

Answer (score 0):

Just open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Enter your pasdword and wait. Now you have the normal JRE on your computer.