# Where should I install my tar.gz files like java or eclipse?

Tags: software-installation

I am quite new to Ubuntu and I see there are many folders in the root directory (/etc, /usr, /opt etc.). I would like to know if there is a standard folder where I should install java, eclipse and any other tar.gz files that are intended for unpacking and then compiling generally?

Comment: You do not install software in Directories, you just tell apt to install a package (In fact, in linux, a programm can possibly have files in all of these mentioned directories). tar.gz is a archive format like .zip or .rar. You can unpack it, not install it. You can install .deb files in ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

In general you do -not- install software using `tar.gz` files. These files are containers that hold software (that might contain software to install but normally you get is all done and ready for you to use). You use either Ubuntu software center or debian installer files to install software.

- Eclipse: https://askubuntu.com/a/118377/15811
- Java: [https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/java)

So there should not be a need to use tar files for these 2 pieces of software.

But if you still want to continue with this: for these types of installations the advised location to extract `tar.gz` files is `/opt/`. The [Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) Standard says:

> /opt : Add-on application software packages
>
> Purpose: /opt is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I will opt for... `/opt`.

> **/opt** - This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not part of the default installation.

More about: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html.

Comment: I'd vote +1 funny if I could ;)