# "error: cannot execute binary file" when trying to install Eclipse IDE on 13.10

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I am trying to install Eclipse IDE using a file `eclipse-rcp-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`

I have followed all the steps mentioned in
[How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

But I am still not able to launch Eclipse:

```
error : cannot execute binary file
```

I have already installed jdk 1.7.

```
uname -i
i686
```

Comment: Hi, now error is removed but after launching nothing is happening... I can't see any splash window coming. just some id is being generated every time like 7774

Answer (score 1):

**Eclipse** is provided by Main Ubuntu Repository. Best method to install is in that way.

It can be installed by :

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde openjdk-7-jre eclipse-platform junit junit4  libhamcrest-java libasm3-java openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Comment: Hi Dumindu,I have run the command you have mentioned. what is next step i should do to launch the eclipse

Comment: As I am very new to this...

Comment: can you please share how should I proceed to learn this new thing, as of now I have just pasted the command you have send but what actually things work I want to know. I'll be thankful to you If you share your knowledge.

Comment: Was that installation completed without any error message? If so, on the dash search for the eclipse icon.

Comment: Yup, there is no error and I have successfully launched the eclipse. thanks alot

Comment: You can install applications easily with `sudo apt-get install <package name>` command. Most of the freely available applications are in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com). You have to search here before search in web. Software Center is having a copy of that repository. You can either easily install apps with it. If you new to ubuntu and need more guide there are some posts I have made [here](http://allfreeubuntu.blogspot.com)

Comment: Hi Dumindu. Please tell me how to install the latest oracle version in Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Oracle java is not given by Ubuntu main repository. It doesn't support all the open source platforms. best is open jdk. If you want to somehow install it, you can use webupd8team repository and install it. Follow this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/295596/224082) for it.