# how to insatll eclipse on ubuntu13.10

Tags: eclipse

Hi I want to install the eclipse from scratch, please let me know how can i do this, in case if I have previous eclipse installed how can i remove it completely from the ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

Remove the previously installed eclipse by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get purge eclipse
```

Then install eclipse by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse).