# getting error while installing eclipse in my system

Tags: eclipse

I am following this article for installing Eclipse in my linux system.
[How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

1. i extracted the `eclipse.tar.gz`
2. `sudo -i`
3. `cp -r eclipse /opt`

in the 3rd step i am getting this error.

```
cp: cannot stat `eclipse': No such file or directory
```

the real name of the tar file was `eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz` which i renamed to `eclipse.tar.gz`

what i am doing wrong?thanks in advance.

Comment: post the real eclipse.tar.gz file name.

Comment: eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz

Comment: post the output of `ls | grep eclipse`.

Comment: its giving no output

Comment: Try `exit` and then `ls | grep eclipse`.

Comment: its showing 'eclipse'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Exit out of the `root` by running `exit` command.
- Then run,

  ```
  sudo cp -r eclipse /opt
  ```
- After that,login into root account by,

  ```
  sudo -i
  ```
- Then follow from the 4th step in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/145018/202806).

This is because after you logged in as root  by running `sudo -i` command,the copy command `cp` searches for `eclipse` directory inside the `/root` folder.But you actually extracted eclipse into the `/home/$USER` folder.

> [image]