# How are we able to run eclipse.exe in ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was following instructions to manually setup eclipse kepler in Ubuntu 14.04.

> Next create an executable for Eclipe at ~/bin/eclipse with your favorite text editor by typing vi ~/bin/eclipse or nano ~/bin/eclipse into the command line. Add the following content:

```
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/mozilla/"
export ECLIPSE_HOME="$HOME/opt/eclipse"

$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```

> Finally, allow the script to be executed:

--From [EclipseIDE:Preparing your System](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE)

I am new to linux so I was just curious to know following things:

1. Why we are setting `export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/mozilla/"` for eclipse? How this is related to eclipse?
2. What is `$*` doing in `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*`?
3. How are we able to run `eclipse.exe` in ubuntu? I think  `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse` is running `eclipse.exe`?

My questions could be very basic but I would appreciate any reference/answer. I have tried to search for answer but I am not able to find it.

Comment: Eclipse has its own version for linux. You are following the wrong instructions. Go to this page, it has the right instructions : http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse

Comment: I am more interested to know the answer of the question rather than setting up eclipse.

Comment: exe are windows programs

Comment: Could someone enlighten me about how my 3 questions are duplicate to referred link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why we are setting `export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/mozilla/"` for eclipse? How this is related to eclipse?

This is for browser support. Eclipse uses browser to display web pages developed in it.

---

> What is `$*` doing in `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*`

It is variable substitution. It is replaced with command-line script parameters during script execution. Also, `$@` is used for this purpose.

---

> How are we able to run `eclipse.exe` in Ubuntu? I think `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse` is running `eclipse.exe`

`Exe`s are for Windows. In Linux, executable binary files usually don't have any extension (though it's possible to create and run files with any extension you like). Scripts have `.sh` extension and self-extracted archives often have `.run` extension. In fact, particular file is executable if it has *execution bit* which is a special attribute of the file. [Read More...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable#Operating_system)

Comment: Your last sentence needs improving: it is perfectly possible to create a file "executeme.exe" and have it run on Linux ;) Linux just does not care for extensions (those are for human readability). This is what makes it impossible: `MS-DOS executable PE  for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit`  (file *.exe).

Answer (score -2):

This question ask many times.
Linux dose not support any "*.exe" executable to run directly.
if you want to run any windows executable file in linux then you have to install "wine".

but i have an question "why you are used windows eclipse to linux ?"
because Eclipse is Open Source and also available in All Linux versions.
Just go to [Eclipse native site](http://eclipse.org/) and download it for linux. they also guide you to how to run downloaded eclipse in linux.