# Unable to find where eclipse got installed

Tags: eclipse

Today I installed JDK on my ubuntu VM using command sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk.But i can't figure out where exactly it has got installed, will I need to configure the Java in my VM so that it can be used by eclipse.
In windows we change the system variable to set up Java.What do i need to do in ubuntu?

Comment: Please post a second question concerning the eclipse problem. Please add how you installed eclipse.

Comment: On a second thought... calling `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` will **not** install eclipse. It will install the java jdk. This will be needed later to run eclipse, but is something completely different. So right now, you don't have eclipse installed. You still need to that. Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse

Comment: Since Eclipse will run in that Java VM, it should have no problems finding out where it's located. That's how it behaved on my system anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and call:

```
dpkg -L openjdk-7-jdk
```

This will list all files installed from the .deb-package.