# Can't figure out how to run eclipse (missing JDK/JRE)

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse, jdk

I'm very new to Linux and coding, I'm really interested in learning and really want to contribute to this process here at Ubuntu as soon as possible.

I downloaded Eclipse Luna. When I try to run it I get the error message:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/alexnchannan/Eclipse/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

*I get it. Eclipse needs a java JDK or JRE - I've been on google, all kinds of sites but honestly I'm just not getting the process here, I've downloaded Java from the site, but can't figure out how I'm supposed to correlate it or whatever its called with Eclipse to get Eclipse to run.*

Can someone please explain to me, **step by step**, in plain english **as simply as possible** how I can get Eclipse up and running and start diving into learning some code, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Eclipse?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Java Development Kit (JDK) on your Ubuntu. Open some terminal program and use the following command: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the Oracle JDK (or JRE).

The installation is a little bit more complicated because there is no official Debian package.

However, the following script should help you to make this installation :
https://github.com/RapazP/install-java