# How do you uninstall manually installed Eclipse?

Tags: xubuntu, software-installation, eclipse

I installed eclipse by using the method in this link
@bitsbuffer: [How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse/145018#145018?newreg=7d870ac1de4549e2bf9d2c86433b0b81)

It is easy to install but anyone knows how to delete eclipse after using this method?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is follow the reverse order of the steps that are listed to install eclipse:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-6-jdk
sudo rm -rf /opt/eclipse
sudo rm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/eclipse44
```

Finally, remove `eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz` and the `eclipse.XX.YY` directory from the location where you downloaded it initially.

The only thing that I do not know is how to remove `eclipse.desktop` from your desktop.

Comment: The `eclipse.desktop` file should be installed in `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`, since that's the default location for `desktop-file-install`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.....

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse

rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

This will remove eclipse and all its dependencies.

Comment: I do not think that this will work, because eclipse was installed from a tarball, not using apt-get, thus apt-get can not remove it.