# Shortcut keys don't work in Eclipse when I change keyboard language

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, eclipse

When I change my keyboard layout from *En* to another language (Persian), the shortcut keys do not work in the new language.

For example <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> didn't save my edit in a text file.

Comment: Probably because S doesn't exist in that location anymore. Check the File menu of a program with saving capabilities to see the new shortcut.

Comment: in eclipse IDE ctrl+s should save note.  when i use English keyboard layout thats work but when i change layout didn't work

Comment: It doesn't work because you changed the layout, meaning S is no longer on the S key. What language did you change to? And try my suggestion.

Comment: What physical keyboard type and what other language selected in keyboard layout? And system language is still En, right?

Comment: it is standard lap top keyboard. and i change language to Persian. this problem happening when i use eclipse IDE

Comment: In the menu bar under File, is "Save" still listed as "Ctrl+S" when the keyboard is set to Persian?  Are other apps. OK? By the way, when you reply to a persons comment, you should include @username so that person gets an alert.

Comment: @user3169 yes Save listed as Ctrl+s and other apps Ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This longstanding bug ["Shortcut keys doesn't work with Arabic and other non-English keyboard"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=61190), which affected all non-Latin keyboard layouts, has now been fixed as of version 4.7.2.

However, the version of Eclipse in the repositories is out of date, so you will need to install the latest version, which is available from the [Eclipse website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), and not by using the package manager.

More help on installing this way is also available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse).