# Will a manually installed program over a program isntalled by repository be replaced back on upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, eclipse

I had Eclipse installed from apt-get, but I needed Mars version so I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse), but I forgot to remove the older version first. If a new version comes out in the repository, will it revert back the version of Eclipse I installed in Unity / desktop. In alternative, if I remove through apt-get, will it delete the links I created? What about dependencies?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, it depends. This is one of the potential problems when installing from source, the names and locations of libraries and binaries can conflict between apt (apt-get) and `sudo make install`

There are 2 general solutions:

**First** - Installing source code into `/usr/local` - minimizes conflicts with system files in `/usr`

This is what I generally do

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

**Second** - Probably better, use check install

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

This makes a .deb from your source code and thus works better with `apt`. The package can then be installed and removed similar to any other .deb.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

You would then put the package on hold

see [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

and then update the package, manually downloading the source code and re-compiling (with checkinstall) or taking it off hold and using the ubuntu repositories (apt).

Note: IMO installing into /usr/local is LEAST likely to result in problems with system files as it is cleaner (keeps the source files and system files completely separate). checkinstall is very relilable, but, if there is a conflict you can break the system.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse version in the repositories is old, make a clean cut:

Remove the package via

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
```

and remove your installation in `/opt`. After that, install Eclipse Mars again. Use the new [Eclipse Installer](https://eclipse.org/downloads/).