# How to install the latest stable version of 'Mars Eclipse' on machine running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, java, eclipse, text-editor, ide

I'm a PHP developer and I'm using SublimeText editor for PHP coding on my machine that runs on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS(64-bit) operating system.

I don't have installed any software related to Java(like jdk, jre, etc.)

Now I want to install and use Eclipse Mars for AngularJS coding.

How should I install it and run it?

Please provide me step by step instructions for the same. If there are any command which I can execute from the terminal please provide me the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Eclipse?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before installing eclipse you need to install java , you can either install JRE or JDK .

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

or

If you are going to use eclipse for java development, then you can install JDK

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Download the latest eclipse package from here http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux

move the package to the /opt directory

```
sudo mv eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz /opt/
```

Unzip the package by typing the below command

```
cd /opt
sudo tar -xvf eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```