# Eclipse won't start after upgrading to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, eclipse

I just upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04 LTS, and suddenly Eclipse won't start. Here's the Eclipse log file:

```
!SESSION 2016-08-28 19:43:46.941 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-08-28 19:43:47.899
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-08-28 19:43:47.899
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.compare.core_3.5.200.dist.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare.core 2 0 2016-08-28 19:43:47.899
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.icu.text_3.6.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare.core 2 0 2016-08-28 19:43:47.899
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.icu.util_3.6.1.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-08-28 19:43:47.899
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.8.1.dist.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2016-08-28 19:43:47.899
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-08-28 19:43:47.900
```

... several pages of similar log error messages later ...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-08-28 19:43:48.011
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Anyone else encountered this?

Edit: [upgrading to Eclipse 4.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse) gives this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/_____/eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/_____/eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0.v201206081400/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/_____/eclipse/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/_____/eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/_____/eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 18800a
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/_____/eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

[image: Screenshot]

There seems to be a bunch of missing dependencies:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(Eclipse:17614): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install unity-gtk-module-common:i386
```

but get this message:

```
Note, selecting 'unity-gtk-module-common' instead of 'unity-gtk-module-common:i386'
unity-gtk-module-common is already the newest version (0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Trying to install overlay-scrollbar just says it's already the latest. Trying overlay-scrollbar:i386 gives this message:

```
Package overlay-scrollbar:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I also tried downgrading Java to 1.7 using `sudo update-java-alternatives`, which also doesn't remove the initial error

Comment: After upgrade Java is 1.8 but do your eclipse upgraded and compatible with Java 1.8 ? Please check that. Which version of eclipse you use and java version by default system shows ?

Comment: `java -version` gives `openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)` I'm using eclipse 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Thats it. Eclipse 3.8 doesn't seems to work with java 8. So you need to install eclipse 4.2 (Luna) if you need to use Java 8. And I prefer to use Oracle Java rather than open jdk. Go ahead with the  eclipse 4.2 and oracle java 8.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried upgrading Eclipse and downgrading Java and neither solved it however.

Comment: Don't downgrade java. If u are using 64 bit OS , use oracle jdk 8 64 bit and eclipse 4.2 64 bit if not if ur os is 32 bit then everything could be 32 bit.

Comment: My OS is 32-bit. Tried installing eclipse 4.2 but a whole bunch of dependencies are missing.

Comment: post output or screenshot .

Comment: I've posted screenshot and output. I don't understand why packages would be missing, as I told it not to remove any packages when I did the ubuntu upgrade

Comment: Your answers seems to be wrong. You said your OS is 32 bit but your java version op shows its installed 64 bit that could be no way possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44616/discussion-between-sagar-bhooshan-and-samgak).

Comment: post the op of the following  uname -a; lsb_release -a; java --version;

Comment: You're right, it's a 64-bit OS, I was confused with another machine I was upgrading at the same time. Still, I didn't actually select 32-bit any time during the upgrade.

Comment: output is `Linux chris-Latitude-E5420 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)`

Comment: Ended up just installing Eclipse Neon and it works. Thanks for your assistance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well I recommend you to install Oracle JDK 8 64 bit and download Eclipse 4.2 64 bit tar file from official website and extract it and double click on the eclipse executable file.