# How to Install/execute JCrypTool on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: permissions, extract

I'd like to install/execute JCrypTool on my Ubuntu 14.04

How should I do it?

-- info from comment --

I am using jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86.tar.gz, 
I have extracted it to home directory, but it doesn't work. I attempt to do the following, but it results in error:

```
artur@artur-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo tar xzvf jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86.tar.gz 
[sudo] password for artur: 
tar (child): jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now tar: Child returned status 2 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now 
artur@artur-Inspiron-3558:~$
```

Am I doing something wrong?

PS:

Thank you for your support, though I still get problems with installing this program. Since it requires at least Java 8(and I have it), it gives some error related to JDK:

```
artur@artur-Inspiron-3558:~$ cd jcryptool
artur@artur-Inspiron-3558:~/jcryptool$ ./JCrypTool 
JCrypTool:
GTK+ Version Check
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/artur/jcryptool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
JCrypTool:
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-jar /home/artur/jcryptool//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /home/artur/jcryptool/JCrypTool
-name JCrypTool
--launcher.library /home/artur/jcryptool//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /home/artur/jcryptool//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 4a0030
-data @user.home/Documents/.jcryptool
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-jar /home/artur/jcryptool//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a [known issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/817749/544264) with the combination of Ubuntu 14.04, Eclipse 3.8 and Java 8.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/817778/544264) specifies:

> Eclipse 3.8 doesn't seems to work with java 8. 
>  So you need to
>   install eclipse 4.2 (Luna) if you need to use Java 8.  And I prefer to
>   use Oracle Java rather than open jdk.

**In order to Install/execute JCrypTool on Ubuntu 14.04 you need the following:**

- Install eclipse 4.2
- Install Java 8
- Download `jcryptool-0.9.9` tar file, and `tar xzvf` in your preferred folder.

---

I've downloaded the 64 bit version (as my Ubuntu is 64 bit) of `jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz` from [here](https://www.cryptool.org/en/jct-downloads/stable).

I've opened it in my home directory using:

```
tar xzvf jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz
```

And run it using:

```
cd jcryptool
./JCrypTool
```

There is no need to install it in `/usr` (unless you would like to share it with other users, etc)

Comment: @ArturoGonzalez, I agree with Yaron, that it isn't clear what this program is, and where should it be installed. So please tell us as much as possible about it. Then we have better chances to really help you.

Comment: I am using jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86.tar.gz, I have extracted it to home directory, but it doesn't work.

I attempt to do the following, but it results in error:

artur@artur-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo tar xzvf jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86.tar.gz
[sudo] password for artur: 
tar (child): jcryptool-0.9.9-linux.gtk.x86.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
artur@artur-Inspiron-3558:~$ 

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ArturoGonzalez - updated my answer, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Yaron thank you very much, but unfortunately it didn't work. I have updated my question and added some details