# Do I need to download any IDE to run a Java program or can I just use my terminal?

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse, ide

Also if I need one then which IDE should I go for and which package (most probably eclipse)?

My system: HP pavillion g6-1200TU with 2 GB Ram,64 bit,Intel Core i3-2330M with 2.2 ghz, with Intel HD graphics 3000, 500gb HDD

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse IDE is quite heavy for i3 processor with 2GB RAM and not recommended unless you need to use the project explorer and stuff. If you have to install eclipse, [follow this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

else if you've simple programs:

To compile the file, open your terminal and type

```
javac filename.java
```

To run the generated class file, use

```
java filename
```

But to do this you need to have the Java JDK installed in your computer. You can install it with the instructions in [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/a/88058/176889).

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need an IDE to run Java programs. For that you need only a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) - this  provides both a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) that enables the system to run Java programs, and a Java Class Library (the set of dynamic libraries used by java programs at run time).

You can check that you have a JRE by typing

```
java -version
```

This will show you a JRE if you have one; if not, then you should install a package, for example

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Or `openjdk-8-jdk` if you plan to do any development.

You can launch java applications from the terminal by calling `java`, for example:

- a `.class` file such as `myjavathing.class` would be run with `java myjavathing`
- for a `.jar` for example `cookie.jar` use the `-jar` option: `java -jar cookie.jar`

If a Java program fails to run, this is usually because some additional libraries need to be installed. Searching for the error message you get on Stack Overflow usually helps you discover which package you need to install to provide the missing libraries!