# Uninstall eclipse 3.8 which was already on my computer

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded eclipse luna v4.4 and extracted the files in my home folder
Then I tried to run it from the terminal by typing eclipse and got an error "eclipse is not installed".
I typed "sudo apt install eclipse-platform", I got a message that this will use up about disk space, i confirmed and eclipse was installed.
When i typed eclipse it started eclipse 3.8 which i believe was waiting 'dormant' in my machine.
So it appears that I have only installed an older version of eclipse and not v4.4.
Although I can ran eclipse 4.4 I don't like the idea of having two different eclipse version on my machine. Plus I can't run v4.4 from terminal.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

You installed eclipse from the repository after downloading a newer one.
Remove the apt installed one :

```
sudo apt remove eclipse-platform
```

Check the [answer  here](https://askubuntu.com/a/145018/401032) to be able to start eclipse from command line.

Answer (score 1):

You've made the same mistake that I made yesterday when installing Eclipse on my computer.

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Remove the `eclipse` software which you currently have installed (package name `eclipse-platform` on my computer): `sudo apt-get purge eclipse-platform`
2. Return to the extracted Luna folder.
3. Here's the step where you originally made the mistake: you need to run `eclipse` with **`./eclipse`**, not with `eclipse`. That tells it to run `eclipse` in the current directory. Otherwise it searches the PATH variable, doesn't find `eclipse` and tells you that `eclipse` is not installed.

## Explanation (if you are interested in the reason why ...)

Ubuntu frequently packages many applications in their repositories, but it happens that the versions are outdated. This is why the Ubuntu version of `eclipse` is 3.8 while the latest now is 4.6 (Neon).

To avoid this, application developers frequently bundle their applications in an archive file. When you extract this archive file, it does not install it for the whole system, but rather you (the user)  only. This is why the PATH variable is *not* updated to reflect it.

If you want instructions on how to update the PATH, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I installed eclipse and tested these commands I found on the Internet.
The following commands should uninstall and purge eclipse

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*
rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

May the Source be with you.

Comment: who is the Source?