# how to install eclipse with only c\c++ and not for others from terminal?

Tags: eclipse

i want to install eclipse in my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS only for c\c++. but whenever i typed the command `apt install eclipse-cdt` **it installs with Java which i don't want**

i can download only c\c++ package from their website but i want to know that is their any way to do it with terminal.

i also tried uninstall the Java packages but uninstall button is disable their.[this is image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkcQV.png) (but unable in windows 10)

thus i want to install clean eclipse only with CDT c\c++ which is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on this but I believe to use IDE specific builds, you have to compile yourself. For the C\C++ builds I believe you need the eclipse-cpp-neon-3 source

https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neon3

Comment: Bruce sir, i already know this way but is their any way that i can do it from terminal?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse

Comment: overall it should install just fine from CLI - it doesn't appear to require a GUI to install

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is itself written in Java, so it requires the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), regardless of which programming language you plan to develop in. That's why "java" is a dependency of eclipse in the package manager. If you plan to do Java development, you'll also need the Java Development Kit (JDK). If you plan to do C/C++ development, you'll need the eclipse-CDT plugin (there are other plugins which provide support for other programming languages.)