# Eclipse installation error on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: java, eclipse, openjdk

I got the following error during installation:

```
 ~/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage (file:/home/shri/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Here is my log file:

```
 !SESSION 2019-01-28 22:19:48.479 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=11.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2019-01-28 22:19:49.344
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1301)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-01-28 22:19:49.352
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar/ was not resolved.
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-01-28 22:19:49.363
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-01-28 22:19:49.363
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2019-01-28 22:19:49.363
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-01-28 22:19:49.364
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you look up your question in the Eclipse Forum, which has a [Special advice](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/89/) for issues related to the installation and the first steps on Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Which version of eclipse are you using? The first output looks like standard warnings and no error. Are you facing issues in compiling/building/running?

Comment: If you are using Java 9 you might find [this illuminating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Answer (score 0):

EClipse is a big IDE, and like most big packaged application they often focus on LTS release more than intermediate releases. I guess you should have less troubles using a LTS for your development.