# Unable to install Eclipse

Tags: 18.04, eclipse

I need to install `eclipse` for school, so that I could help with an Android project. Everyone else at my school uses Windows , so they cannot help me. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and this fails to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package eclipse is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'eclipse' has no installation candidate
```

I've searched for an answer, but nothing seems to help. Would anybody mind helping me?

Comment: Or using the Snap: https://snapcraft.io/eclipse

Comment: Yes, thank you. I feel silly for not finding that one :(

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what is eclipse?

Comment: @NathanielSturtz eclipse is an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You could install it via snap

Snap is the easiest and fastest way to do it

Run the following command

```
sudo snap install eclipse --classic
```

Or you could open software center and search for eclipse and the install it from there.

Comment: I should mention that I can't get snap to work:

    error: system does not fully support snapd

Comment: @diogenesjunior what about software center

Comment: I haven't messed with it much. I learned from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse) that I must have Java installed first, so I suppose that was my problem.

Comment: @diogenesjunior you just search for the word eclipse and then click install. Like google playstore or apple appstore